# Return from page not triggering `INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo`

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I have a `NavigationPage` with `ContentPage`s. When I use the back arrow provided by the `NavigationPage` instead of `INavigationService.GoBackAsync`, my implementation of `INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo` is never called. Based on browsing the source, it looks like Prism doesn't listen for the event when the `NavigationPage` does a pop.

Is there something I need to do to make it hit that or is there no way to tap into that? Is there a specific reason not to hook in to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue.  You can follow the request here:

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/issues/634

The problem is that there is no unified API for Prism to use in order to call INavigationAware when a Page is popped.  There are many more scenarios that just NavigationPages that must be considered.  For now, you can simply hook into the event yourself in a custom NavigationPage and call the INavigationAware events.  Xamarin will be implementing an API for Prism to use n a future release.  Until then, you must handle this manually.